# C++ passing function arguments to another lambda

Tags: c++, function, lambda, boilerplate, type-deduction

I have a bunch of boilerplate code in regards to my lambdas. here is an crude

For the moment lets assume that myClass looks like this:

```
class myClass
{
   public:
    std::function<void(int,int)> event;
    std::function<void(std::string)> otherEvent;
    <many more std::function's with different types>
}
```

With its lambdas assigned during runtime as such:

```
myClass->event =[](T something,T something2,T something3)
{
    yetAnotherFunction(something,something,something3);
    //do something else.
}
```

How I want it to look like:

```
void attachFunction(T& source, T yetAnotherFunction)
{
    source = [](...)
    {
       yetAnotherFunction(...);
       //do something else.
    }
}
```

so that I can call something like this:

```
attachFunction(myClass->event,[](int a,int b){});
```

and

```
attachFunction(myClass->otherEvent,[](std::string something){});
```

I simply want to pass along the parameters and make sure that they match.

How do I wrap this into a function, Assuming that I will have an undefined number of parameters and different types?

Thanks!

Comment: Is `eventList` a `map` ? What is its type ?

Comment: ah yeah bad example I will edit. I am using a class with runtime defined lambdas such as std::function<void(std::string button)> OnClick

Comment: Still not clear. What is `event ` ? Will the lambda attached to the event always take 3 parameters and only the internal function signature changes ?

Comment: No the number of parameters is unknown. it can be one or three or more. what changes are the number of parameters and their types.

Comment: I edited and added an example of what the class might look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve this. This is my solution:

```
template <typename R, typename... Args>
void attachEvent(std::function<R(Args...)>& original,std::function<R(Args...)> additional)
{
    original = [additional](Args... args)
    {
        additional(args...);
        std::cout << "Attached event!" << std::endl;
    };
}
```

The original function is extended by additional, it erases previous functionality from original lambda.

Here is example usage:

```
  std::function<void(float,float,float)> fn = [](float a ,float b,float c){};
  std::function<void(float,float,float)> additional = [](float a,float b,float c){std::cout << a << b << c << std::endl;};

  attachEvent(fn,additional);
  fn(2.0f,1.0f,2.0f);
```

Which should print in sequence:

212

Attached Event!